# Magento-2 Mobile menu setup

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, css, navigation, mobile-menu

Yesterday, I was having an issue with horizontal top menu as I wanted to make them invisible on **frontend**.
I made it invisible by using css as:

```
body.cms-my-homepage div.main-menu.menu-style-2{display:none}
```

And it worked for me but this code also disabled the mobile menu. Is there any other way, means by which I can enable the mobile menu
or specify a new mobile menu?

Comment: For hiding menu only for desktop, you can use media query for above CSS

Comment: yeah how can i forget that! thanks for reminding me @pawan

Comment: Welcome @Laiba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code in your CSS for displaying menu in your mobile device

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    body.cms-my-homepage div.main-menu.menu-style-2{display:block}
}
```

Comment: Hi Aasim Goriya, can i get help regard hamburger menu https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328503/57334 thank you